# Cannot create object xml for client soap request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to make a client request for a soap web service, and when I try to create the xml with simplexml_load_string it says this:

```
Error: Cannot create object
```

With no any other errors, so I can't figure it out what am I doing wrong, my code is bellow, I hope you can help me to solve this issue

```
<?php
        $produccion = false; //Cambiar a verdadero por producction
        $url = "http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php";

        //print_r($_POST);

        $posts = $_POST;

        if ($produccion == false) {
            $posts['nombre'] =
                $posts['apellido'] =
                    $posts['direccion'] =
                            $posts['pisodto'] =
                                $posts['localidad'] =
                                    $posts['partido'] =
                                        $posts['provincia'] =
                                            $posts['telefono'] =
                                                $posts['celular'] =
                                                        "PRUEBA";
        }

        $Datos = "<cliente>
        <nombre>".$posts['nombre']."</nombre>
        <apellido>".$posts['apellido']."</apellido>
        <calle>".$posts['direccion']."</calle>
        <altura>".$posts['altura']."</altura>
        <pisodto>".$posts['pisodto']."</pisodto>
        <localidad>".$posts['localidad']."</localidad>
        <partido>".$posts['partido']."</partido>
        <provincia>".$posts['provincia']."</provincia>
        <telefono>".$posts['telefono']."</telefono>
        <celular>".$posts['celular']."</celular>
        <num_tarjeta>".$posts['num_tarjeta']."</num_tarjeta>
        </cliente>";

        $myXMLData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.maxisistemas.com.ar">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <ws:AltaSolicitud soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <cXml>'.$Datos.'</cXml>
        <Clave>123ClubMilaMREST5</Clave>
        </ws:AltaSolicitud>
        </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';

        $xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object"); //<-Here is the error
        $client = new SoapClient($url);
        $result1 = $client->AltaSolicitud($xml);
        $result2 = $client->ConsultaPuntos($xml);

?>
```

Comment: Don't they provide wsdl data?

Comment: @michael look at the $url variable from code, I think you mean this? -> http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php?wsdl

Comment: You have to add `?wsdl` at the end of the `$url`. Also, you have to send string, not SimpleXML object as parameter for `AltaSolicitud` and `ConsultaPuntos`. I think that all tags with `soapenv` will be unnecessary as well.

Comment: @michael with your commented changes -> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php' : Premature end of data in tag html line 2 in G:\wamp\www\bsmart\PHPtoXML2\enviarxml.php:104 Stack trace: #0 G:\wamp\www\bsmart\PHPtoXML2\enviarxml.php(104): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://ws.maxir...') #1 {main} thrown in G:\wamp\www\bsmart\PHPtoXML2\enviarxml.php on line 104

Answer (score 1):

I can't get an answer but

> => "ERROR. ACCESO NO PERMITIDO"

But with the right credentials and data you should be able to get the information you need with below class.

Simply set your data in the `setData()` function / call it first and then call AltoSolicitud() with `Clave` as parameter

```
class Request extends \SoapClient
{
      public $Datos;


    public function __construct(array $options = [], $wsdl = 'http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php?wsdl')
    {

        $options = [
            'features' => 1,
            ];
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $Clave
     * @return string
     */
    public function AltaSolicitud()
    {
        $Data = $this->getData();
        try {
            return $this->__soapCall('AltaSolicitud', [
                $Data
            ]);
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
            return ($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

        public function setData($posts,$produccion = false)
    {
        if ( ! $produccion) {
            $posts['nombre'] =
            $posts['apellido'] =
            $posts['direccion'] =
            $posts['pisodto'] =
            $posts['localidad'] =
            $posts['partido'] =
            $posts['provincia'] =
            $posts['telefono'] =
            $posts['celular'] =
                "PRUEBA";
        }

        $Datos = "<cliente><nombre>".$posts['nombre']."</nombre>
        <apellido>".$posts['apellido']."</apellido>
        <calle>".$posts['direccion']."</calle>
        <altura>".$posts['altura']."</altura>
        <pisodto>".$posts['pisodto']."</pisodto>
        <localidad>".$posts['localidad']."</localidad>
        <partido>".$posts['partido']."</partido>
        <provincia>".$posts['provincia']."</provincia>
        <telefono>".$posts['telefono']."</telefono>
        <celular>".$posts['celular']."</celular>
        <num_tarjeta>".$posts['num_tarjeta']."</num_tarjeta></cliente>";
        $Clave = '123ClubMilaMREST5';


    $myXMLData = <<<XML
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.maxisistemas.com.ar">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:AltaSolicitud soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <cXml xsi:type="xsd:string">' . str_replace(PHP_EOL,'',$Datos) . '</cXml>
         <Clave xsi:type="xsd:string">' . $Clave . '</Clave>
      </ws:AltaSolicitud>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
XML;
        $this->Datos = $myXMLData;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $Cod_Tarj
     * @param string $Clave
     * @return string
     */
    public function ConsultaPuntos($Cod_Tarj, $Clave)
    {
        return $this->__soapCall('ConsultaPuntos', [$Cod_Tarj, $Clave]);
    }

    public function getData(){
         return $this->Datos;



}



 $request = (new Request)->setData($_POST,false)->AltaSolicitud();
 var_dump($request);
```

Comment: Is that Codeigniter? If it's that I need to do this work on pure php, but nice response

Comment: Just asking because it gives me some errors, and the Clave parameter is also on my code is 123ClubMilaMREST5

Comment: How would I use that class to call?

Comment: Shouldn't give errors, but it has no Auth. Copy the edited code to a file and run it, should work

Comment: Like this? $client = new SoapClient($url);
        $result1 = $client->setData($posts)->AltaSolicitud($xml);

Comment: No, simply copy the entire code from above and run the file, it will do everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78653/discussion-between-ricardo-rios-and-michael).

Comment: The issue is that The variables comes from a form, and are dynamics, so can we continue on chat?

Comment: Wait a second, I'll rewrite it

Comment: Now you can POST to this file and it will read the values, if you want to change to production, change the parameter $request = (new Request)->setData($_POST, false)->AltaSolicitud(); <<<---- false to true

Comment: Thanks, now it says ERROR. ACCESO NO PERMITIDO (Error, forbidden access), figuring out why

Comment: Yes, I'm having this too, seems like you need to be authenticated

Answer (score 1):

@Ricardo

I was able to make your code work by adding "wsdl" to the url. After this change I did not see the error "Cannot create object".

```
 $url = "http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php?wsdl";
```

I made some other minor changes, but I don't think they are important:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $myXMLData ); //or die("Error: Cannot create object"); //<-Here is the error
$client = new SoapClient( $url , array('trace' => 1 ));
$result1 = $client->AltaSolicitud($xml);
echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```

And the result was the same "ERROR. ACCESO NO PERMITIDO" already noted. To me it appears that the soap parameter `<Clave>123ClubMilaMREST5</Clave>`is incorrect or expired. I noticed this because the word is almost the same in Italian (chiave = clave = key). I assume this is an API key like many web services require?

**SOAP Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:AltaSolicitudResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.maxisistemas.com.ar">
            <return xsi:type="xsd:string">ERROR. ACCESO NO PERMITIDO</return>
        </ns1:AltaSolicitudResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```